# Cookie problem when deploying mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 app and am setting a cookie to hold data.

It works fine when test in IE with VS2008.

When I deploy to IIS6 site no cookie is created.

Site uses HTTPS.

I am checking Temporary Internet Files folder for the cookie.

Any ideas of things to check?

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if the cookie you are setting has the [Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain.aspx) property set, the value should correspond to the domain you are hosting your web site under II6.